# AWS Batch Service taking longer time to launch instance

Tags: aws-batch

I am observing that if a new batch job has been submitted shortly after the last instance in a compute environment has shut down it takes over 10 minutes for Batch to add a new instance to the Compute environments even if CE's have available resources.

Can anyone who is aware please let me know if this is an expected behavior from AWS side or if there is a way to fix it.

Thanks
Chaitanya

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour.  There is a thread [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=927268) which includes a response from the AWS team.

> Further, it is important to note that the AWS Batch resource scaling
>   decisions occur on a different frequency. Upon receiving your first
>   job submission, AWS Batch will launch an initial set of compute
>   resources. After this point Batch re-evaluates resource needs
>   approximately every 10 minutes. By making scaling decisions less
>   frequently, we avoid scenarios where AWS Batch would scale up too
>   quickly and complete all RUNNABLE jobs, leaving a large number of
>   unused instances with partially consumed billing hours.

(p.s. I notice that it looks like yours was the last comment in the linked thread, but I post this anyway for the benefit of others)

Comment: can it be changed, such that it scales up/down immediately on a per job basis? 1 instance per job. That link is dead.